# Adobe upload cannot read stream in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, drupal

The file is small about 4 to 5Kb.

I am trying to upload a fillable pdf to an Apache server.

The pdf has a submit button which uploads the PDF to a Zend IndexController using

```
$request=$this->getRequest();
$tempFile=time().'.pdf';
file_put_contents("data/tmp/".$tempFile, $request->getContent());
```

I am now trying to do the same in Drupal 7 to no avail. $_POST and $_FILES are both empty.

If I use an HTML form the file will upload, however, I want the end user to click on the button within the form.

I also tried

```
file_put_contents("data/tmp/".$tempFile, "php://input");
```

Which created the PDF file on the server, but it unfortunately only contains the text "php://input".

Can someone please advise how to do this?

Comment: `file_put_contents("data/tmp/".$tempFile, file_get_contents("php://input"));`

Answer (score 0):

Dale's answer

```
file_put_contents("data/tmp/".$tempFile, file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

is correct